# How to Toggle Interior.Color using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have a form control button that, using VBA, changes the selection to either `Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)` if the selection has no interior color, or `Selection.Interior.Color = xlNone` if the interior colors of the selection are already red. Effectively toggling a Boolean property. For example, if I want to toggle the WrapText property of a selection, I can use

```
Sub ToggleWrapText()
'    Toggles text wrap alignment for selected cells
     If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
         Selection.WrapText = Not ActiveCell.WrapText
     End If
End Sub
```

The following procedure does not work because it simply makes the selection `xlNone` and will not change back to red when I click the control form button a second time.

```
Sub mcrToggleRed()
'   Toggle the color for selected cells
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Select Case Selection.Interior.Color
            Case xlNone
                Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Selection.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried an `If...Then...Else` loop which only has the same result as the `Select...Case` loop above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an Immediate If (`IIf`) for this kind of thing:

```
Sub mcrToggleRed()
    With Selection.Interior
        .Color = IIf(.Color = xlNone Xor .Color = 16777215, RGB(255, 0, 0), xlNone)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Note:** The actual problem with your original code was caused by the fact that you were testing for `xlNone` as the default value. [Gary's Student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student) actually posted another answer which tested for `RGB(255, 255, 255)` instead - this is the *actual* default value for the `.Color` property of a cell.

Although in my code I've used `16777215` (which is the return value of `RGB(255, 255, 255)`) - I originally overlooked the fact you were testing for the wrong value, something that Gary's answer would have made clearer if it were still here.

---

(Alternate solution that Gary posted (I've added [with his permission](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30830299#30830299)) )

```
Sub mcrToggleRed()
'   Toggle the color for selected cells
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Dim r As Range
        For Each r In Selection
            If r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then '//<~~ NOTE the RGB value
                r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If
        Next r
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That works beautifully to turn the `ActiveCell` red. I changed this to `Selection.Interior.Color` and the whole selection turns red. However, while the selection area is red, if I run the mcrToggleRed() procedure again (i.e., click the button a second time), the selected range remains red. I would like it to turn back to xlNone. Your code turns the selection area red, but does not toggle it back to xlNone. Any hints?

Comment: EUREKA!! Perfect solution @MacroMan! Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to click the green tick on the left to mark as the answer if it helped.

Comment: I noticed that the procedure doesn't work without the `Xor .Color = 16777215` part. Why is that? BTW...SO won't let me promote your answer until I have 15 reputation. If you can uptick my question, I may have enough points to uptick your answer.

Comment: The default `.Color` value of a cell is `16777215` - not `xlNone` which has a value of `-4142` (The `Xor` was me messing with something else - a normal `Or` will do the same job here)

Comment: I'll UV your question on the basis that it was _actually_ a useful question - you don't have to UV my answer unless you feel it's worthy of it.